# How to use an LSTM model to make predictions on new data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I have trained an LSTM model on a dataset that includes the following features: Amount, Month, Year, Package, Brewery, Covid, and Holiday. The model is used to predict the amount. I preprocessed the data using the following code:

```
values = stella_values.values
training_data_len = math.ceil(len(values)* 0.8)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(values.reshape(-1,1))
train_data = scaled_data[0: training_data_len, :]

x_train = []
y_train = []

for i in range(12, len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i-12:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])
     
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
```

The model architecture looks like this:

## Layer (type)       Output Shape         Param #

lstm (LSTM)         (None, 12, 128)      66560
dropout (Dropout)   (None, 12, 128)      0
lstm_1 (LSTM)       (None, 12, 32)       20608
dropout_1 (Dropout) (None, 12, 32)       0
lstm_2 (LSTM)       (None, 16)           3136
dropout_2 (Dropout) (None, 16)           0
dense (Dense)       (None, 32)           544
dense_1 (Dense)     (None, 16)           528
dense_2 (Dense)     (None, 1)            17

Now, I want to use this model to make predictions on new data. Specifically, I have a new data point with the following values:

```
Month = 1
Year = 2019
Package = "Thicket"
Brewery = "Cristal"
Covid = 0
Holiday = 0
```

How can I use the trained model to predict the Amount value for this new data point ? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried using `model.predict([1,2019,"Thicket","Cristal",0,0])` but this gave me an error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 12, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 12, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='lstm_19_input'), name='lstm_19_input', description="created by layer 'lstm_19_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
```